# Remove hl command using notepad++ or Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, soul

During the review process of a manuscript, I was asked to highlight changes according to the comments of the reviewers. I used the soul package in combination with the color package. These two really do the job, but now I am desperately looking for a way of removing the hl command without removing the inner part.
For instance, from:

```
\hl{This is a default text.}
```

to

```
This is a default text.
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462522/vim-latex-remove-command-around-word-phrase-easily), using vim for a very similar problem. Since I am not familiar with vim, I am seeking a solution for an editor I am familiar with, like texstudio or notepad++.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need balanced braces (e.g. to match `\ht{This \textit{is} a default text}`), this would be a very simple regular expression and therefore can easily be done using search&replace. If you need balanced braces AFAIK notepad++ also supports recursive pattern. Don't know if TeXstudio supports [balancing pairs or groups or recursive pattern](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html). I'm not using any of these editors, so I cannot test it and will not write an answer. (BTW: You could also redefine `\renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}` in the document preamble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've used `\hl` only for this purpose, you can remove the highlighting at LaTeX with adding:

```
\renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}
```

to your document preamble.

If you really need to replace the `\hl{…}` by the content of the argument in the source code, this could be possible using search&replace with a regular expression. If you don't need to handle balanced braces (e.g. `\hl{Test \textit{and} test}`) the search expression could be `\hl{\([^}]*\)}` and the replacement `$1` resp. `\1` as shown here:

```
echo '\But{and \hl{Test} and}' | sed 's/\\hl{\([^}]*\)}/\1/'
```

or (with extended regular expressions enabled):

```
echo '\But{and \hl{Test} and}' | sed -E 's/\\hl\{([^}]*)\}/\1/'
```

results in

```
\But{and Test and}
```

For multiline `\hl` commands with commands inside, this would be more complicate. Because `perl` should be available with both TeX Live and MiKTeX, you can use (note: quoting in this example has been done for a unix shell like `bash`):

```
perl -0ne 's/\\hl{//g;$i=0;while(/./gs){$i-- if $& eq "{";$i++ if $& eq "}"; if ($i<1){print $&}else{$i=0}}' <infile.tex >outfile.tex
```

This also works with text above multiple lines and commands inside the `\hl` argument. For example, if your `infile.tex` is:

```
This is a \hl{test
  \textit{and
    does} also work} as wanted.
```

the `outfile.tex` would be:

```
This is a test
  \textit{and
    does} also work as wanted.
```

Unfortunately, currently it fails, if `\hl{…}` is used inside another argument,like here:

```
\But{This is a \hl{test
  \textit{and
    does} not work} as wanted.}
```

(would result in

```
\But{This is a test
  \textit{and
    does} not work} as wanted.
```

so maybe I should think about it a little longer, if you really need a solution for such constructs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You use perl or what exactly?

Comment: @Zorg I'm always trying to use, what is simplest for my purpose. So, I would not have started using `\hl` directly but I would have defined a new markup, e.g., `\Change`, *using* `\hl` and therefore would have to just redefined `\Change` to not longer highlight the changes.

Comment: You are right, this seems to be the better way. But, please correct me if I am wrong, still after redefining the \Change command \Change{random text} would be in the TeX file, right. I need a way to resubmit my paper without the necessary commands for highlighting.

Comment: @Zorg If you have to remove the command from the source, see my answer from: “If you really need to replace the \hl{…} by the content of the argument in the source code”. Depending on what you really have, there are two suggestions with different limitations. And no, for the first one (using a single regular expression) you don't need to use `sed`. TeXstudio and Notepad++ also support the usage of regular expressions.